# SQLITE: merging rows into single row if they share a column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, aggregate-functions

From a previous post, I have the following view in sqlite3:

```
CREATE View AttendeeTableView AS

SELECT  (LastName || " " || FirstName) as AttendeeName,  
        CompanyName, 
        PhotoURI,
        CompanyAttendeeRelation.CompanyId,
        CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId 

FROM    Attendee 
JOIN    CompanyAttendeeRelation on CompanyAttendeeRelation.AttendeeId = Attendee.AttendeeId 

ORDER BY LastName;
```

Now, since the data is generated from a many-to-many relation between `Attendee` and `Company`, I can get results such as:

```
Doe John | company A | johnPic.png | 1 | 15
Doe John | company B | johnPic.png | 2 | 15
```

What I'd like to do is, in cases where there's more than one company (like above), create a query that outputs:

```
Doe John | company A company B | johnPic.png | 1 2 | 15
```

And another that outputs:

```
Doe John | company A | company B | johnPic.png | 1 | 2 | 15
```

So I need to know essentially how to merge a specific column for rows that have different
values in that table.

Any ideas?

Just in case, `company A company B` in the first query is obviously text concatenation, That is, something along the lines of `(row1.CompanyName || " " || row2.CompanyName)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the aggregate function **[`group_concat(X)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)** for that:

```
SELECT (a.LastName || " " || a.FirstName) AS AttendeeName
     , a.PhotoURI
     , group_concat(c.CompanyName) AS Companies
     , group_concat(c.CompanyId)   AS CompanyIds
FROM   Attendee AS a
JOIN   CompanyAttendeeRelation AS ca ON ca.AttendeeId = a.AttendeeId
JOIN   Company                 AS c  ON c.CompanyId = ca.CompanyId
GROUP  BY a.LastName, a.Firstname, a.PhotoURI;
```

(Using table aliases to make it shorter and easier to read.)

`NULL` values are excluded from the result. [The manual:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

> the concatenation of all non-NULL values

The **order of elements** in `CompanyIds` and `Companies` is arbitrary, according to [the manual](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.

Also note that "arbitrary" is not the same as "random". `group_concat`, like other aggregate functions, processes the set of rows in the order received. Without any `ORDER BY`, that order is dictated by whatever query plan is executed. There is no natural order in tables of relational databases (you cannot rely on insert order *at all*). But both instances of `group_concat()` in the same `SELECT` list process rows in the *same* order so that the 1st ID in `CompanyIds` corresponds to the 1st name in `Companies`.

You can impose your order with `ORDER BY` in a subquery. It's an implementation detail, but it's highly unlikely to change. Like:

```
SELECT (LastName || " " || FirstName) AS AttendeeName
     , PhotoURI
     , group_concat(CompanyName) AS Companies
     , group_concat(CompanyId)   AS CompanyIds
FROM  (
   SELECT a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.PhotoURI, c.CompanyName, c.CompanyId
   FROM   Attendee AS a
   JOIN   CompanyAttendeeRelation AS ca ON ca.AttendeeId = a.AttendeeId
   JOIN   Company                 AS c  ON c.CompanyId = ca.CompanyId
   ORDER  BY 1,2,3,4,5  -- or whatever you need
   ) AS sub
GROUP  BY LastName, Firstname, PhotoURI;
```

[The manual](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) about the (optional) ordinal numbers in `ORDER BY`:

> If the ORDER BY expression is a constant integer K then the expression is considered an alias for the K-th column of the result set (columns are numbered from left to right starting with 1).

Use the `GROUP BY` list as leading `ORDER BY` expressions for best results.

Don't do anything with the derived table *after* ordering that might rearrange it (like joining the subquery to another table etc.)

Finally, note that similar aggregate functions in other RDBMS can behave slightly differently. Related:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)
- [GROUP_CONCAT ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631210/group-concat-order-by)

Comment: The manual said `The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary`. Does that mean that the concatenated `CompanyIds` doesn't necessarily match in order the `Companies`?

Comment: @Jason: I added more to address that (among other things).

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038351/sqlite-select-data-from-multiple-rows-returned-as-one-row) will help you turn

```
Name     | company
---------+----------
Doe John | company A
Doe John | company B
```

into

```
Name     | company-1 | company-2
---------+-----------+----------
Doe John | company A | company B
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a inner select might help, like:

```
CREATE View AttendeeTableView AS

SELECT  (LastName || " " || FirstName) as AttendeeName,  

(
  select CompanyName
FROM    Attendee A_innner 
JOIN    CompanyAttendeeRelation CAR  /* is this where company name is? */  
ON      on CAR.AttendeeId = A.AttendeeId /* if not remove the joins and CAR */
WHERE   A_inner.last_name = A_outer.last_name and
        A_inner.first_name = A_outer.first_name
),
PhotoURI,
CAR.CompanyId,
CAR.AttendeeId 


FROM    Attendee A_outer 
JOIN    CompanyAttendeeRelation CAR_outer  
ON      on CAR_outer.AttendeeId = A_outer.AttendeeId 

GROUP by LastName,FirstName
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName;
```