# GROUP_CONCAT ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I've [a table](http://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqfkhfeV83Tm05VnU4cV9ZSWZlMUNTQzRZUUJQTFdQZUptOEJkdXkyVXFIYmM) like:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| client_id | views | percentage |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|         1 |     6 |         20 |
|         1 |     4 |         55 |
|         1 |     9 |         56 |
|         1 |     2 |         67 |
|         1 |     7 |         80 |
|         1 |     5 |         66 |
|         1 |     3 |         33 |
|         1 |     8 |         34 |
|         1 |     1 |         52 |
```

I tried `group_concat`:

```
SELECT li.client_id, group_concat(li.views) AS views,  
group_concat(li.percentage) FROM li GROUP BY client_id;

+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| client_id | views             | group_concat(li.percentage) |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|         1 | 6,4,9,2,7,5,3,8,1 | 20,55,56,67,80,66,33,34,52  |
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

But I want to get the views in order, like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| client_id | views             | percentage                 |
+-----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|         1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 | 52,67,33,55,66,20,80,34,56 |
+-----------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: are the values of views and percentage in the table stored as comma separated values?

Comment: No they aren't stored like that but I made them by my query i.e., with group_concat

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Sort GROUP\_CONCAT values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995373/mysql-sort-group-concat-values)

Answer (score 495, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in this way:

```
SELECT li.client_id,
  group_concat(li.views ORDER BY li.views ASC) AS views,
  group_concat(li.percentage ORDER BY li.views ASC) AS percentage
FROM li GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `group_concat(li.percentage ORDER BY li.views ASC)` so that the percentages come out in the order that matches the views, as requested by the original post?

Comment: @aleroot, Is this query MySQL specific?

Comment: Yes, GROUP_CONCAT is a MySQL only function, however a similar result can be achieved on other database with a surrogate function ...

Comment: If ordering the group_concat by the same expression you're group_concat()ing, you can just write `group_concat(li.views ORDER BY 1)`.  Easiest!

Comment: @KaiCarver comment is true above query doesnt give the right response

Comment: @iec2011007 I've adjusted the response, but when I answer questions here, I'm usually writing fast with the aim to give you the hint to solve the problem, then anyone can adapt the solution to his own context, isn't it fair enough ?

Comment: Chill.. I was just pointing so that if anyone just copy pastes the snippit doesnt run into error.

Comment: Thx @aleroot so handy this order by inside the group concat

Comment: in case you are also using separator :  `SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u.RegionName,'-',u.UserName) ORDER BY u.RegionName SEPARATOR '@@')`

Comment: Can we add limit in group_concat ?

Answer (score 27):

The group_concat supports its own order by clause

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

So you should be able to write:

```
SELECT li.clientid, group_concat(li.views order by views) AS views,
group_concat(li.percentage order by percentage) 
FROM table_views GROUP BY client_id
```

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
SELECT li.clientid, group_concat(li.views ORDER BY li.views) AS views,
       group_concat(li.percentage ORDER BY li.percentage) 
FROM table_views li 
GROUP BY client_id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat

Answer (score 15):

**You can use *SEPARATOR* and *ORDER BY* inside the *GROUP_CONCAT* function in this way:**

```
SELECT li.client_id, group_concat(li.percentage ORDER BY li.views ASC SEPARATOR ',') 
AS views, group_concat(li.percentage ORDER BY li.percentage ASC SEPARATOR ',') FROM li
GROUP BY client_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In IMPALA, not having order in the GROUP_CONCAT can be problematic, over at Coders'Co. we have some sort of a workaround for that (we need it for Rax/Impala). If you need the GROUP_CONCAT result with an ORDER BY clause in IMPALA, take a look at this blog post: http://raxdb.com/blog/sorting-by-regex/

Comment: New link should be https://www.codersco.com/blog/2016/06/sort-by-regex/

Comment: the URLs for this sort-by-regex are no longer available :-(