# Output Group Concat with Conditional Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have sql table like this:

```
Table A

NIP        BIDANG      MAYOR       MINOR
1            A          ZZ          YY
2            A          ZZ          XX
2            A                      YY
```

and i have another table :

```
Table B

NIP        Keahlian     Nilai
1             XX          2
1             YY          0
1             ZZ          3
2             XX          4
2             YY          2
2             ZZ          3

Table C
NIP           Score       Limit
1               10          15
2               20          15
```

Based on that table, i want to create a table with conditional statement like this :
if socre <= limit, than saran = xxx else saran = group concat from mayor minor but sorted by the high value in coloumn Nilai in Table B. So, the output like this :

```
NIP       Saran
1          XXX
2        XX, ZZ, YY
```

How to make it, please help me.

Comment: It seems that data in Table A is not necessary to produced the required output. Is that correct?

Comment: well its possible to do but your first table is irrelevant in this case , since the data you want could be gathered from last 2 tables.

Comment: Table A is necessary, when keahlian in table B have Nilai 0. that keahlian remains displayed as long as there is keahlian in mayor minor for that NIP.

Comment: @user3440030 Cold you please explain how the above rule would be applied if Table C had Score=15, Limit=10 for NIP=1?

Comment: @JosephB Saran for NIP 1 = ZZ, YY

Comment: @user3440030 Thank you for the clarification. See the modified query in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets you the required output. You can use ORDER BY with the GROUP_CONCAT function. Also, Limit is a reserved word, so I renamed the column as Limitx. Please see this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ec97/3).

```
SELECT
    NIP,
    CASE SIGN(Score-Limitx)
        WHEN -1 THEN 'XXX'
        ELSE (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.Keahlian ORDER BY b.Nilai DESC) FROM TableB b WHERE b.NIP = c.NIP)
    END Saran
FROM
    TableC c;
```

**EDIT**:

Here is the modified query, based on the requirement that Keahlian must exist in either MAYOR or MINOR column of TableA:

```
SELECT
    NIP,
    CASE SIGN(Score-Limitx)
        WHEN -1 THEN 'XXX'
        ELSE (SELECT 
                GROUP_CONCAT(b.Keahlian ORDER BY b.Nilai DESC) 
              FROM TableB b
              INNER JOIN
              (SELECT NIP, MAYOR Keahlian
               FROM TableA
               UNION ALL
               SELECT NIP, MINOR
               FROM TableA 
              ) TableA_list
              ON TableA_list.NIP = b.NIP AND TableA_list.Keahlian = b.Keahlian
              WHERE b.NIP = c.NIP
              )
    END Saran
FROM
    TableC c;
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bb52/2)

**References**:

[Related Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631210/group-concat-order-by)

Comment: But i want to based on mayor minor, if keahlian has a value that does not exist in table A, then the value will not be displayed in output.