# How to use order by along with group_concat

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in database

```
ID   |  AId            | field           | Value        | internalOrder |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 86 |             193 | h1              | v1           |             1 |
| 43 |             193 | default         | default      |             2 |
```

I want to get concatenated field,value and internalOrder sorted by internalOrder groupedBy Aid.
So that the results should be like

```
193 | h1,default | v1,default | 1,2
```

I have tried few things.

```
select Aid,group_concat(field), group_concat(value), group_concat(internalOrder order by internalOrder ASC) from table1 group by Aid order by Aid;
```

This produces results like this:

```
|193 | default,h1 | default,v1 | 1,2
```

Which is wrong.

How to produce the desired results?

Comment: you can check the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631210/group-concat-order-by

Comment: `group_concat(internalOrder order by ID desc)` and same for other perhaps ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below-

```
select Aid,group_concat(field order by internalOrder ASC), 
group_concat(value order by internalOrder ASC), 
group_concat(internalOrder order by internalOrder ASC) 
from table1 group by Aid order by Aid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `order by` in all the `group_concat()` operations.  This is a local "order by".  It doesn't apply to the whole query:

```
select Aid, group_concat(field order by internalOrder) as fields, 
       group_concat(value order b internalOrder) as values,
       group_concat(internalOrder order by internalOrder ASC) as internalOrders
from table1
group by Aid order by Aid;
```

Also note that this is separate from the `order by` on the query itself.  That order by does not have a consistent effect on the order in the `group_concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will useful to you.

```
select Aid,group_concat(field order by field), 
group_concat(value order by value), 
group_concat(internalOrder order by internalOrder ASC) 
from table1 group by Aid order by Aid;
```

Thank you..

Comment: Although he doesn't make it clear, I think what they want is to order all grouped values by `internalOrder`, whereas your code will order each grouped value by itself.