# mysql subquery does not keep the order WHY?

Tags: mysql, sql

good morning guys, I have this table named 'soccer_team'

```
id  first_name  surname   player_number
1   Alexis      Sanchez   7
2   Petr        Cech      33
3   Hector      Bellerin  24
4   Olivier     Giroud    12
5   Theo        Walcott   14
6   Santi       Cazorla   19
```

if I launch this command,

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname,' #',player_number) as 'i' from soccer_team order by player_number
```

it gives me

```
i
Alexis Sanchez #7
Olivier Giroud #12
Theo Walcott #14
Santi Cazorla #19
Hector Bellerin #24
Petr Cech #33
```

which is correct

however when I run

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i,' ') as 'players'
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname,' #',player_number) as 'i'
      from soccer_team
      order by player_number
     ) as a;
```

it gives me

```
players
Alexis Sanchez #7 ;Petr Cech #33 ;Hector Bellerin #24 ;Olivier Giroud #12 ;Theo Walcott #14 ;Santi Cazorla #19
```

while it should be

```
players
Alexis Sanchez #7; Olivier Giroud #12; Theo Walcott #14; Santi Cazorla #19; Hector Bellerin #24; Petr Cech #33
```

**

> how to solve the problem I know, I wanted to know why this happens

**

**UPDATE**

> I know how to solve it, what interests me is because it works in this
>   way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP\_CONCAT ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631210/group-concat-order-by)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the order inside `GROUP_CONCAT` provided that you include `player_number` in the subquery.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i ORDER BY player_number ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as 'players' 
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname,' #',player_number) as 'i' ,player_number
from soccer_team 
) as a;
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af25a/2).

Actually, you can simplify by removing the subquery which will still give you the same result

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname,' #',player_number) 
                     ORDER BY player_number ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as 'players' 
FROM soccerteam
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af25a/3).

Comment: . . The `CONCAT()` is redundant in the second query.  `GROUP_CONCAT()` accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: I know how to solve it, what interests me is because it works in this way

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia it is because the outer query tells mysql to sort the value using the specified column.