# Mysql - GROUP_CONCAT - Control order of other / merged columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

Given a table like this:

```
id     number     anotherNumber
1      1          10
2      1          20
3      2          20
4      2          10
5      3          10
```

If I run the query:

```
Select *, GROUP_CONCAT(number)
FROM docs
GROUP BY number
```

I will get:

```
id  number  anotherNumber   GROUP_CONCAT(number)
1   1       10              1,1
3   2       20              2,2
5   3       10              3
```

[see sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb2c7e5/1/0)

However I want to get:

```
id  number  anotherNumber   GROUP_CONCAT(number)
1   1       20              1,1
3   2       20              2,2
5   3       10              3
```

Basically I want the numbers in the `anotherNumber` column to be sorted in DSEC order - it should always be the highest one.

I know you can put an [`ORDER BY`in the `GROUP_CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8631210/228450) but this will only affect the concatenated values, not the "merged ones". So is there a simple way?

Comment: It is strange to be aggregating the group by column.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Agree with @TimBiegeleisen.  The result will always be `number` repeated `COUNT(*)` times.  What's the point, except to discover the number of records in each group in a very roundabout way?

Comment: IMHO `COUNT(*)` would be more appropriate than `GROUP_CONCAT(number)`. Same information with less data.

Comment: @tim agree, but this is a very simplified example focusing on the isssue. in my real life case i am joining tables, etc. and the values in the concat group are not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
Select MIN(id) AS ID, number, MAX(anotherNumber) AS anotherNumber,
       GROUP_CONCAT(number)
FROM docs
GROUP BY number;
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb2c7e5/8/0)**

You should always wrap columns that are not specified in `GROUP BY` with aggregate function(unless they are functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns and your RDBMS supports [ANSI-99 Optional feature T301, Functional dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544322(v=sql.105).aspx))

Comment: ...unless they are functionally dependent on the `number` column.

Comment: That is the ANSI standard (except for Oracle).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQL Server also does not allow columns that are not in `GROUP BY`

Comment: Oh yes it does.  If I group by a primary key column I may select _any_ column in that table, because they are functionally dependent.  Only Oracle doesn't follow this, among the major databases, because it's really old school.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you sure? [Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=401cae2856f47b0d4dc9c21c71694dce) or I am missing something obvious `SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns` and [T301, Functional dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544322(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would be grateful if you could provide demo for SQL Server

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What matters more than SQL Server or Oracle is MariaDB, which doesn't support it. And they seem not even to plan it :-(

Comment: It looks like [you are right about SQL Server](http://rextester.com/XVRU93057) but Postgres and MySQL do support this part of the ANSI standard.  I upvoted you, by the way, but your language `always` wrap is not necessarily true on every database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sure, I've added note about it

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the easy way to get the desired result:

```
SELECT id, number, MAX(anotherNumber) AS anotherNumber, GROUP_CONCAT(number)
FROM docs
GROUP BY number;
```

I have also attached my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb2c7e5/18).

You can check it. Good Luck!