# MySQL Query Returns Different Results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I'm having a strange problem with the following query:

```
SELECT
    doubles_team_members.doubles_team_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(members.first_name,' ',members.last_name) SEPARATOR ' & ') team,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(members.city,', ',members.state) SEPARATOR ' & ') location,
    doubles_teams.deleted_by_id
FROM
    doubles_team_members
JOIN
    doubles_teams USING(doubles_team_id)
JOIN
    members USING(member_id)
JOIN
    memberships ON members.member_id=memberships.member_id
WHERE
    (memberships.expiration_date>=CURDATE() OR members.lifetime=1) AND 
    (doubles_teams.deleted_by_id IS NULL OR doubles_teams.deleted_by_id=0) AND 
    (members.deleted_by_id IS NULL OR members.deleted_by_id=0)
GROUP BY
    doubles_team_members.doubles_team_id
HAVING
    team='Van Williams & Derek Williams';
```

Sometimes I get zero, one, two or three results. I should always get three results. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you add some data please? Also, what exactly do you mean by "sometimes"? Like, when you run the query twice right after another or rather one day it's two and another day it's three records in the results?

Comment: Something to consider: your group_concat has no inherent order. If MySQL randomly orders your members differently (e.g. derek first), the having clause may not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Solarflare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6248528/solarflare), `GROUP_CONCAT()` could produce your `team` string in a random order, e.g. `'Van Williams & Derek Williams'` or `'Derek Williams & Van Williams'`.

To remedy this, you can [use an explicit `ORDER BY` within the `GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631273/14015737), e.g.:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(members.first_name,' ',members.last_name) ORDER BY first_name DESC SEPARATOR ' & ') team
```

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) and  [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3a0ef7a6dbe95aa3a067dc37cae1e28e) for an example.

Comment: The ORDER BY did the trick! I now get the same results every time. Thanks so much! This was driving me nuts!