# MySQL - Selecting Users With A List Of Their Borrowed Book In DESC Ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose I have a table of User

**User** :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alisa |
| 2 | Bryce |
| 3 | Ryan |

and a table of Book

**Book**:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Book 1 |
| 2 | Book 2 |
| 3 | Book 3 |
| 4 | Book 4 |
| 5 | Book 5 |
| 6 | Book 6 |

and a table of **Loan**:

| id | user_id | book_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 6 |

I have created a query that allows me to see users with their borrowed book. The query code is as below:

```
SELECT u.name as User, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.title) as Borrowed_Books
  FROM Loan l
  JOIN User u ON u.id = l.user_id 
  JOIN Book b ON b.id = l.buku_id
 GROUP BY u.id;
```

The result would look like this:

| User | Borrowed_Book |
| --- | --- |
| Alisa | Book 1,Book 2 |
| Bryce | Book 3,Book 4 |
| Ryan | Book 5,Book 6 |

But I want it so the grouped books are ordered descending (Book 2, Book 1; Book 4, Book 3; etc...). How could I do so? I tried using ORDER BY b.title DESC but it would give me an error.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631210/group-concat-order-by

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `ORDER BY` clause following the argument of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function
such as

```sql
SELECT u.name as User, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.title ORDER BY b.title DESC) as Borrowed_Books
  FROM Loan l
  JOIN `User` u ON u.id = l.user_id 
  JOIN Book b ON b.id = l.book_id
 GROUP BY u.name
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0944c3100ce4c51c7d23908f9494f673)</kbd>

As a side note : All non-aggregated column(s)(in this case `u.id`[*provided that it would be needed of course*]) should be listed next to `GROUP BY` for *only_full_group_by mode* of SQL

Comment: I didn't know you could add it inside the function. Thank you my friend!