# Merge rows into 1 rows with separate columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
FirstName |LastName |OtherName |admim_no| ExamCategory | subject | Exam| Score| Grade 
Anthony   | Tee     | Tony     | 1000   | MockExams2014|Chemistry| PP1 | 12   | D+
Anthony   | Tee     | Tony     | 1000   | MockExams2014|Biology  | PP1 | 50   | C+
Moses K.  | Ndu     |          | 1001   | MockExams2014|Chemistry| PP1 | 65   | B+
Moses K.  | Ndu     |          | 1001   | MockExams2014|Biology  | PP1 | 85   | A
```

What I want to achieve in sql server 2012 is for each exam category I have admission_no grouped into one row and then the columns subject, exam, score, grade be placed as individual columns for the 2nd row so that you have for example admission_no 1000 and all different data for the columns (subject, exam, score, grade) as single row. I cant get how to go around it. I have tried the below unsuccessfully.

My result should like below

```
Anthony |   Tee |    Tony  |  1000|  MockExams2014|Chemistry|   PP1 |  12| D+   Biology|   PP1 |   50| C+
```

[SQLITE: merging rows into single row if they share a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867397/sqlite-merging-rows-into-single-row-if-they-share-a-column)

[image]

Comment: So for `admission_no 1000` you want two `subject` columns, two `Grade` columns, etc.? That is, all those last 4 columns repeated as many times as different subjects that `admin_no` has?

Comment: You can do this with a dynamic pivot or a dynamic cross tab. There are tons of questions on this topic around this site and the entire internet. Just search for dynamic pivot and will find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would allow to concatenate then repeated values into on row you would be able to work with a joined subquery using XML PATH, show as addition (2) below.
To get the repeated values as columns you could count the maximum rows for admim_no and create a dynamic sql using as many left joins as necessary to get the needed columns.

```
/* test data
Create table TestX (FirstName varchar(50) ,LastName varchar(50),OtherName varchar(50), admim_no int,ExamCategory varchar(50), subject varchar(50), Exam Varchar(50), Score int,grade varchar(50))
Insert into TestX Values ('Anthony','Tee','Tony',1000 ,' MockExams2014','Chemistry','PP1',12,'D+')
Insert into TestX Values ('Anthony','Tee','Tony',1000 ,' MockExams2014','Biology','PP1',50,'C+')
Insert into TestX Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Chemistry','PP1',65,'B+')
Insert into TestX Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Biology','PP1',85,'A')
Insert into TestX Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Physiks','PP2',12,'D+')
*/


Declare @maxcnt int
Declare @cnt int
Declare @Dyn1 varchar(max)
Declare @Dyn2 varchar(max)

Select @maxcnt=MAX(cnt) from
       (Select COUNT(*) as cnt from TestX Group by admim_no ) a




Set @Dyn1='
;With CTE as
(
Select *, Row_Number() over (Partition by admim_no order by admim_no ) as rn  from TestX
)
Select CTE0.*
'
Set @Dyn2='
           From CTE CTE0'
Set @cnt=1
While @maxcnt>1
  begin
  Set @Dyn1 = @Dyn1 + ',CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.subject
                       ,CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.Exam
                       ,CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.Score
                       ,CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.grade'
  Set @Dyn2 = @Dyn2 + ' 
                       LEFT Join CTE CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'
                       on CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.rn=CTE0.rn + '+Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+' 
                       and CTE' + Cast(@cnt as varchar(5))+'.admim_no=CTE0.admim_no'   
  Set @maxcnt=@maxcnt-1
  Set @cnt=@cnt+1
  end 
Set @Dyn2 = @Dyn1 + @Dyn2 + '
                       where CTE0.rn=1'
Print @Dyn2
Exec(@Dyn2)
```

the generated SQL for the test data provided would look like:

```
;With CTE as
(
Select *, Row_Number() over (Partition by admim_no order by admim_no ) as rn  from TestX
)
Select CTE0.*
,CTE1.subject
                       ,CTE1.Exam
                       ,CTE1.Score
                       ,CTE1.grade,CTE2.subject
                       ,CTE2.Exam
                       ,CTE2.Score
                       ,CTE2.grade
           From CTE CTE0 
                       LEFT Join CTE CTE1
                       on CTE1.rn=CTE0.rn + 1 
                       and CTE1.admim_no=CTE0.admim_no 
                       LEFT Join CTE CTE2
                       on CTE2.rn=CTE0.rn + 2 
                       and CTE2.admim_no=CTE0.admim_no
                       where CTE0.rn=1
```

the result like

```
Anthony Tee Tony    1000     MockExams2014  Chemistry   PP1 12  D+  1   Biology PP1 50  C+  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Moses K Ndu NULL    1001     MockExams2014  Chemistry   PP1 65  B+  1   Biology PP1 85  A   Physiks PP2 12  D+
```

The easier way with one column for outpu as initial mentioned (2) would look like this:

```
Declare @a table (FirstName varchar(50) ,LastName varchar(50),OtherName varchar(50), admim_no int,ExamCategory varchar(50), subject varchar(50), Exam Varchar(50), Score int,grade varchar(50))
Insert into @a Values ('Anthony','Tee','Tony',1000 ,' MockExams2014','Chemistry','PP1',12,'D+')
Insert into @a Values ('Anthony','Tee','Tony',1000 ,' MockExams2014','Biology','PP1',50,'C+')
Insert into @a Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Chemistry','PP1',65,'B+')
Insert into @a Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Biology','PP1',85,'A')
Insert into @a Values ('Moses K','Ndu',NULL,1001 ,' MockExams2014','Physiks','PP1',12,'D+')


Select FirstName,LastName,OtherName,admim_no,ExamCategory
, STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + subject +', ' + Exam +', ' + CAST(Score as varchar(20)) + ', ' + Grade 
              FROM @a a2 where a1.admim_no = a2.admim_no            
              FOR XML PATH (''))       
             , 1, 1, '') as subjectExamScoreGrade       

from  @a a1
Group by  FirstName,LastName,OtherName,admim_no,ExamCategory
```

Comment: Thank you. Great Man. Kudos. I m so greatfull. Keep up. Don't know what to give you. Thank you once more.