# SQLite return multiple rows in a single one

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im pretty new to SQL, and basically I have two tables messages and messagesData:

**messages**:

```
_id    message      sender    conversationId

 1     "text"       'user1'     111111
 2     "otherText"  'user2'     111111
 3     "bla"        'user3'     111111
```

**messagesData**

```
messageId   user     read           received

1           'user1'  1574939944809  1574939944809
1           'user2'  1574939944809  1574939944809
1           'user3'  1574940002929  1574940002929
2           'user1'  1574940002929  1574940002929
2           'user2'  false          1574940002929
2           'user3'  false          1574940002929
3           'user1'  1574940097707  1574940097707
3           'user2'  false          1574940097707
3           'user3'  false          1574940097707
```

And i need to make a query that returns in a single row all the data from the message, and "aggregate" the data from messagesData with the same messageId, something like this:

```
_id    message   sender   conversationId    user                     read                                         received
1      "text"    'user1'   111111            'user1','user2','user3'  1574939944809,1574939944809,1574940002929     1574939944809,1574939944809,1574940002929
```

I tried using the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038351/sqlite-select-data-from-multiple-rows-returned-as-one-row), but as you can see in my case, there is more than 2 data that I want to aggregate ( the amount of messagesData is variable per message)

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and use group_concat() to return the values from `messagesdata` as a comma separated list:

```
select m._id, m.message, m.sender, m.conversationId,
  group_concat(d.user) user,
  group_concat(d.read) read,
  group_concat(d.received) received
from messages m left join messagesdata d
on d.messageid = m._id
where m._id = 1
group by m._id, m.message, m.sender, m.conversationId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gtUSRmf6kWYGj2wptXYo7P/1).
Results:

```
| _id | message   | sender | conversationId | user              | read                                      | received                                  |
| --- | --------- | ------ | -------------- | ----------------- | ----------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------------- |
| 1   | text      | user1  | 111111         | user1,user2,user3 | 1574939944809,1574939944809,1574940002929 | 1574939944809,1574939944809,1574940002929 |
```